# Lotus Notes: how can i check if saved document has been modified

Tags: lotus-notes, lotusscript, lotus

In lotus notes 6.5 , how can i check if a document fields are different than before ?

Now i have put some code in the Queryopen that populate a field "*changes*" with some source document values and in the querysave i check if values that i  had save during queryopen are different from the fields in the source document. If they change i have to update some other documents, in other case i don't have to update anything.

**Is there other simplier solution ?**

Comment: This is how I do it, and I think it's the way most people with this requirement do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take the same document via view lookup in QuerySave. Don't try to take same document via db.getdocumentbyunid (as it will read document from memory which is already modified) (see example below)

```
dim s as new notessession
dim db as notesdatabase
dim view as notesview
dim samedoc as notesdocument
set db = s.currentdatabase
set view = db.getview('lookupview')

' that is how you can get unsaved document from database (but not the one you already updated in QueryOpen event)
set samedoc = view.getdocumentbykey(key, true)

' samedoc - untouched one, form database;
' source - updated document
msgbox samedoc.keyitem(0) ' original value
msgbox source.document.keyitem(0) ' QueryOpen's value
```

Let me know if it does not work.

Comment: But if someone else has changed the doc while you are editing, you will now be comparing your in - memory values against someone else's changes.

Comment: @richardSchwartz that's true :) but in that way user will get replica conflict anyway.

Comment: Yes, that is also true. I guess you have to pick your poison. If you have logic that you trigger when the current user makes changes, comparing against the on-disk doc can generate false positives (logic is triggered even though the user didn't change anything) or false negatives (logic is not triggered because the user's changes are the same as some other user's changes). Theoretically, by checking both the on-disk doc and in-memory values saved in QueryOpen, you could accurately handle all these cases, but I've never actually seen anyone do that.

Answer (score 0):

and you may also want - should be possible in Notes 6.5 - the use of ReplicationConflict settings on Forms 'Merge/NoConflict' or 'Do Not Create Conflicts', if feasible for you.